# Mass SMS issue, singular works

Tags: sms

Using click a tell extension (4.1) with CiviCRM (5.8.2)

When in a contact record can send a SMS with no problem- is delivered straight away.

When using 'Mass SMS' and clicking 'Send immediately' it doesn't send- at all, states on CiviCRM is complete and looking at the contact record it is complete.

Looking at click a tell account it hasn't reduced in monies nor is the SMS in the pending or sent list.

After further testing if I select 'Schedule send' and select one minute past the current time (if the Cron is running every minute) it will send the SMS at the scheduled time.

Is this an extension bug or CiviCRM bug?